# Redis setting TTL to -1 in Java

Tags: java, redis, jedis

```
redisSyncCommand.hmset(key, value);
redisSyncCommand.expire(key, ttl);
```

Have one method where we put (`hmset`) in cache with TTL in the above way.
Due to some exceptions while `hmset` -ing... for the particular key.. it sets the TTL to -1 and hence the key remains in cache forever.. and cache memory usage goes up.

How to ensure it always sets the TTL

Answer (score 1):

I would try to control the exception in Java:

```java
try {
  redisSyncCommand.hmset(key, value);  
  redisSyncCommand.expire(key, ttl);
} catch(Exception ex) {
  // Some log error message
  redisSyncCommand.expire(key, xxx);
  // Or delete the key
}
```

Comment: redisSyncCommand.hmset(key, value)

what if this throws timeout ... but internally it is still setting the key.

so in exception, we will expire.. but may be the completion of caching is happening after that

Comment: I'm no sure if I understood correctly. The `hmset` throws a timeout exception, but the key is stored anyway in Redis, right ? That sounds a bit weird. Please add the exception stacktrace to the question.

Comment: we have the timeout set from our end only, that if redis doesn't respond within X sec, we will timeout.. 

so for our service it timeouts after X seconds, but in redis.actually. the key and the map might be still caching... 

so in exception catch,  expire might not work properly. .

Comment: Redis is fast, really fast, a timeout when the operation is finished correctly doesn't make sense. This sounds to a network or infrastructure issue. Are you trying to store a  very large object (GBs size) ?